# Rxjs: How to implement Observable.first()?

Tags: rxjs, observable

I'm learning RxJs and trying to understand how **Observable.first()** method works under the hood.
[Source code](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operators/first.ts) is pretty messy.

Is there an easy way to implement this method to understand how it works?

*I want to understand exactly **how it works inside**, but not how it can be implemented.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation we see

> Emits only the first value. Or emits only the first value that passes some test.

So the basic behaiour (emits only the first value) is done by keeping track whether the first value has been emitted or not, with a subscriber-level field.

Then `predicate`, `resultSelector`, or `defaultValues` are just a bit of additions to that basic code (basically a `filter`, a `map` or a `default`).

If you want to take a look on the specific code for this operator, the relevant part is `FirstSubscriber._next => FirstSubscriber._emit => FirstSubscriber._emitFinal`, where it uses the `this._emitted` flag to track if it has emitted or not.

Edit: If you wanted to define a custom Rx extension that does what `first()` does without using other basic operators such as `take(1)`, I would do something like this:

```
Observable.prototype.first = function() {
    const source = this;
    return new Observable(observer => {
        let hasSentValue = false;

        return source.subscribe(
            v => {
                if(!hasSentValue) {
                    observer.next(v);
                    observer.complete();
                    hasSentValue = true;
                }
            },
            err => observer.error(err),
            () => {
                if(!hasSentValue) {
                    observer.error("Empty stream");
                }
            });
    });
};
```

*Note: not tested*

Comment: "to that basic code" could you provide basic code here?

Comment: @StepanSuvorov I don't fully understand what you are asking here. By "basic code" I don't mean easy/short, but the code that covers the base behaviour of `.first()`. If you want to take a look on how is that implemented (you are now asking for code), I already pointed you to the relevant part in the Rx repo (`FirstSubscriber._next => FirstSubscriber._emit => FirstSubscriber._emitFinal`)

Comment: I added some code that simplifies what that repo has. It should give you an idea....